# Borrowing a &RefCell results in multiple mutable borrows

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to make a parent objected that creates and manages child objects. It returns `&RefCell` from a factory function which can then be used to borrow the child object. I have condensed the code down to this example:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, cell::RefCell, error::Error};

struct Child(i32);

impl Child {
    pub fn new(id: i32) -> Child {
        Child(id)
    }
}

struct Parent {
    children: HashMap<i32, Box<RefCell<Child>>>
}

impl Parent {
    pub fn new() -> Parent {
        Parent {
            children: HashMap::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn create_child(&mut self, id: i32) -> &RefCell<Child> {
        let child = Child::new(id);
        let cell = Box::new(RefCell::new(child));
        self.children.insert(id, cell);
        return self.children.get(&id).unwrap();
    }

    pub fn beep(&mut self) {

    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut parent = Parent::new();
    let child1 = parent.create_child(1);
    let child2 = parent.create_child(2);
    child1.borrow();
}
```

But as soon as I try to borrow a reference to the child it results in the following compile error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `parent` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> foo\src\main.rs:37:18
   |
36 |     let child1 = parent.create_child(1);
   |                  ---------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
37 |     let child2 = parent.create_child(2);
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
38 |     child1.borrow();
   |     --------------- first borrow later used here
```

Is there a way for me to return a `&RefCell` without it resulting in an error?

Comment: You can't have a reference to an item in a hash map while also mutating the hash map. What if the map needs to grow to a bigger array and needs to move the items?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo That is why the items are boxed, to keep them in the same location on the heap.

Comment: Then alternatively, what if you called `create_child` with the same key? That would drop the value and cause references to be invalid. The borrow checker can't know that the values of `create_child` don't overlap.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo that is a result of making a simple example. A real implementation would have proper unique Id generation.

Comment: So the borrow checker is pointing out the issue with your simple example. The borrow checker isn't magic - it sees you trying to use a mutable reference to something that has an immutable reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Where there is a RefCell, an Rc is probably close by, but for now I made it compile without (and also removed the Box for extra minimalism). Once you try to make this code do something useful that may no longer work.

```
use std::{collections::HashMap, cell::RefCell};

struct Child(i32);

impl Child {
    pub fn new(id: i32) -> Child {
        Child(id)
    }
}

struct Parent {
    children: HashMap<i32, RefCell<Child>>
}

impl Parent {
    pub fn new() -> Parent {
        Parent {
            children: HashMap::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn create_child(&mut self, id: i32) {
        let child = Child::new(id);
        let cell = RefCell::new(child);
        self.children.insert(id, cell);
    }

    pub fn get_child(&self, id: i32) -> &RefCell<Child> {
        self.children.get(&id).unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut parent = Parent::new();
    {
        parent.create_child(1);
        parent.create_child(2);
    }
    let child1 = parent.get_child(1);
    let child2 = parent.get_child(2);
    child1.borrow();
    child2.borrow();
}
```

Comment: The box is required to prevent the RefCell items from moving. This will break when you add new items to the hash map and it reallocates.

Comment: @RickdeWater, you seem to say there is a memory issue when the hash map has to reallocate, but barring bugs in the rust borrow checker, this code compiling proves that there is not.